# What are the requirements to develop login/ Sign up API's to use Magento 2.?

Tags: magento2, rest-api

i am new in magento , but i need to use Rest API's to my mobile app, but i don't know how it is uses this API's ad how can i check these API's.

First what are the requirements to call REST API's in magento based to use mobile apps.

i have a sample megento api's path lists below. 
Please give me any suggestion how to use and how can we develop REST API's to use magento.

https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index_20.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you can check Magento documentation https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/get-started/rest_front.html

Also, I recommend checking this project https://github.com/troublediehard/magento-react-native. It contains a good sample of all basic API usage required for Magento mobile app.

Comment: please give me some documentation. I didn't anything in Apis

Comment: I gave you some documentation in my answer. Please ask a more specific question like at want exact point you stuck.

Comment: how can i get login api

Comment: @nukalasatish you can use the following endpoint for this http://magento.domain/rest/V1/integration/customer/token

Comment: {
"username":"122q1a0517@gmail.com",
"password":"S@tish63"
}
http://www.depoto.com/Beta/rest/V1/integration/customer/token

Comment: I got this key when I was pass the url to keys

Comment: "xn9un9lf7aiaj3flhf3t6rqlrvjv6yto"

Comment: @nukalasatish please send me an email, I'll invite you to the slack so we can discuss. You can find my contacts here https://github.com/troublediehard/magento-react-native

Comment: ok my mail id:satish.n517@gmail.com